# Why is $P(A) \neq P(A|B) + P(A|B^C)$?

Tags: probability

Disprove the following claim:

> For any events $A,B$,  $P(A) = P(A|B) + P(A|B^C)$

I've fiddled with the algebra of the conditionals, but didn't get to anything solvable. I'm not terribly interested in proving this by counterexample -- I want to understand *why* this is not the case. It looks deceptively reasonable to me. Could it be that this does hold for a significant number of cases, but fails under particular conditions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the case when $A$ always happens - then $P(A)=P(A|B)=P(A|B^C)=1$, so the formula fails badly.

The correct equality is $P(A) = P(A|B)P(B) + P(A|B^C)P(B^C)$, which stems from the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) - the reason that this formula, rather than the formula you give, works is because it weights the conditional probabilities by the probabilities of going down each of those paths.

One similar formula that *is* true is that $P(A)=P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^C)$, which can be used with Bayes' formula to derive the above.

Comment: Good call. I knew that this was a perversion of the law of total probability, but didn't spot the correct version.

Comment: Yep - a nice alternative way of understanding the extra factors is actually by recalling [probability trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_diagram_(probability_theory)), which give one of the earliest exposures to conditional probability and how we use it in problem solving. Though, to be honest, this is more showing how the formula works than explaining it.